# WSO2 ESB API does not send http request

Tags: http, get, request, wso2, esb

I'm trying to create an API on wso2esb 4.8.1 that is able to use HTTP GET and POST. When a POST request is received the request has to be dispatched to two endpoints. This works fine and I've not added this piece in the example below.

But the HTTP GET request should be handled in a straightforward manner and this does not work. The request is not being forwarded at all and I'm only seeing a time out message in the ESB logs.

I've used wirehark to see if I see an outgoing request on the wire but this is not the case.

To me the HTTP GET looks pretty straight forward, nothing special at all, but it does not get send out by the ESB. Help would be greatly appreciated!

I've added my API description below:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="myapp" context="/myapp/myservice">
  <resource methods="GET">
    <inSequence>
      <log>
        <property name="Message Flow" value="MyApp MyService API - IN"></property>
        <property name="HTTP_METHOD IS###########" expression="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD"></property>
      </log>
      <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
      <property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
      <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2"></property>
      <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
      <send>
         <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://myserver.com/myapp/myservice/myaction"></address>
         </endpoint>
      </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
     <property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
     <send></send>
  </outSequence>
  <faultSequence>
     <log level="full">
        <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default sequence"></property>
        <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"></property>
        <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"></property>
     </log>
     <drop></drop>
    </faultSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Can you try adding `format="GET"` for the address endpoint, and try? See here - https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Address+Endpoint

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried what you suggested but the requests still timeout. In the log file I also see timeout warnings.